# Add Custom Row To GridView Table

Tags: mysql, asp.net, .net, gridview

I want to add a customized row to a GridView table in ASP.NET.

Specifically, I want to add a row which lists the averages of the columns. I don't want the code to calculate the averages, I only want to know **how to insert a custom row** in the first place.

Examples below...

**Adding custom row at the very end...**

[image: I get error if I try to paste this as plain text, so I just screenshotted what it should look like!]
*Sorry, Stack Overflow keeps giving me an error on post so I just just took a screenshot.*

Feel free to post questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the  `Footer` your custom row (add three textbox for example each one in a column )

Comment: Is there a cleaner way? Also: how can one add the custom row to an arbitrary location: e.g. after the header but before the data.